# Get same HttpSession in portlet and ajax called servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, portlet, httpsession

I want to pass data in HttpSession from a jsp portlet to a servlet. The servlet called from an Oracle AS page portlet with ajax call.
There are many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax), how to do this, but how to pass HttpSession data?
Because (i think) ajax call different url than portlet context (like `$.post( "/app/servlet", data)`), it can't find original session, instead it creates a new one when i try to reach with `request.getSession()`.
The portlet and the servlet are in same war application, currently running in JDeveloper, Apache ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse maps to webserver url: `http://webserver.local/app`, portlet producer registered with connection: `http://webserver.local/app/providers/` and I set the login frequency on the provider registration page to "always".
I put the portlet in a random page `http://webserver.local/path/to/page` and i think that's the reason that portlet on that page generated session not equals with called servlet.

If call jsp portlet on `http://webserver.local/app/felvitel.jsp` and servlet on `http://webserver.local/app/servlet`, than i can get same session, so this is why i'm sure its about url problem.
But the portlet have to use inside a page, not just alone, and i don't know how to map servlet url, or change cookie to find same session.

Now i store session id on jsp page in hidden:
`<input type="hidden" id="sessionkey" value="<%=session.getId()%>"></input>`

...and the javascript create a cookie with `name="JSESSIONID", value=$("#sessionkey").val(), path=/app` and it's working, the servlet gets same session, but that has to be another way i think.

Can i somehow alter cookie from jsp page? I tried to search in cookies and `cookie.setPath("/app");response.addCookie(cookie1);` but looks do nothing, and as i read it have to set somewhere else, not working on jsp pages, it has to be set on header creation.
Or any other solution?

Comment: Sounds like you're investing a lot of effort solving the wrong problem. What's the underlying problem that you want to use? Most likely the use of servlet combined with portlets is wrong. That's why `serveResource` was introduced in JSR-286: To put an end on those ugly workarounds.

Comment: You're right, but that's an old system, not using JSR-286. :( I went to standalone server with apache/php/mysql, and realized how much easier life now. :-)

Comment: so what's the "portlet" that you're talking about? JSR-168? Homegrown?

Comment: Yes, it was an old Oracle 10g portal, 10.1.3 Application Server, not supporting JSR-286.